# Symfony PUT Empty

Tags: php, symfony, put

In Symfony in API I have PUT method and when in Postman I create PUT url and add fields in body and send I enter to action but have empty request and not understand why? I try with parameters in ApiDoc and without and try use annotation * @Put("/projects/{slug}", name="put", requirements={"id"="\d+"}) but still empty request. [scrren](http://uploads.ru/U4Z2T.png)

```
 /**
 * Update existing Projects from the submitted data or create a new Projects at a specific location.
 * @Put("/projects/{slug}", name="put", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Create/Update single Projects",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="level", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="project choice - Senior, Middle+, Middle, Middle/Junior, Junior"},
 *      {"name"="main_skill", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="mainskill project"},
 *      {"name"="name", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="additional information"},
 *      {"name"="duration", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="1 year+, 3 months+, 2 weeks"},
 *      {"name"="location", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="location project"},
 *      {"name"="expected_budget", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="expected_budget project"},
 *      {"name"="start_date", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="start date project"},
 *      {"name"="description", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="description"},
 *      {"name"="employment", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="employment"},
 *      {"name"="project_skills", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project skills project"},
 *      {"name"="markets", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project markets "},
 *      {"name"="platforms", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project platforms "},
 *      {"name"="token", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="is equally md5('email'.secret_word)"},
 *      {"name"="speciality", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project speciality"},
 *      {"name"="type", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="project type - fixed_cost or time_and_material"},
 *      {"name"="rate", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="project rate"}
 *
 *  },
 * statusCodes = {
 * 200 = "Projects successful update",
 * 404 = "Return when project with current slug not isset",
 * 101 = "Secret token is not valid"
 * },
 *  section="Project"
 * )
 *
 *
 * @param  Request $request
 * @param  string  $slug
 * @return mixed
 */
public function putProjectAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
```

$data empty and I look $request and not find my fields ( 
when I try POST method I see my fields in request
help please

Comment: But there is no parameter at all in this API method. What don't you see ?

Comment: Update question. I try with parameters in ApiDoc and without

Comment: Just tried and it works `var_dump($request->request); die();   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#764 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    ["_format"]=>
    string(4) "json"
    ["limit"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["level"]=>
    string(7) "gfdgdfg"
  }
}`

Comment: I have added only one of your parameter 'level'.

Comment: this magic, I select PUT in POSTMAN add fields in body and have empty parameters in request

Comment: Do you send it as json ?: {"_format":"json","limit":"5","level":"gfdgdfg"} ?

Comment: in postman I select for-data, like I use for post method

Comment: Use https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle instead of postman. it will read your annotation and build the correct query for you.

Comment: thanks, send with help sanbox and I have fields in my body. But wnhe I try postman like in sanbox  PUT /projects/ddd.json and have empty request

Comment: Tried with postman it works... PUT request. In payload tab I enter,  `param=toto`, i have:  `object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#11 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["param"]=>
    string(4) "toto"
  }
}`

Comment: thanks, I use sanbox and I have parameters in request

Comment: Answer updated. Feel free to accept, for the help. See you. ++

Answer (score 0):

Tried with postman it works... PUT request. In payload tab I enter:

```
param=toto
```

I have the following output:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#11 (1) { ["parameters":protected]=> array(1) { ["param"]=> string(4) "toto" } }
```

So it might be an incorrect use of Postman.